# Setting Firemonkey control font programmatically in C++

Tags: c++, firemonkey, c++builder-xe7

I have a custom Firemonkey control that extends `TEdit` which is dynamically created on a form.  I am attempting to set it's font size when it is created using:

```
Search->Font->Size = 15;
```

However, the font remains unchanged on the control.

I have another control of the same type that is already on the form which I can change the font size programmatically. I noticed with this control, that if the `Size` setting is set to false in the `StyledSettings` properties I can change the font, whereas if the `Size` setting is set to true, I cannot change the font size.

So, when I create my custom control, I am trying to programmatically set the `Size` property to false, however I cannot figure out how to do so.

I have tried:

```
Search->StyledSettings.Size = false;
```

and

```
Search->StyledSettings = ListBox->StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.ssSize];
```

neither of which will even compile.  How can I make sure this property is removed on my custom control at run time?  Or is there another way I should be setting its font?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, the font remains unchanged on the control.
>
> I have another control of the same type that is already on the form which I can change the font size programmatically. I noticed with this control, that if the Size setting is set to false in the StyledSettings properties I can change the font, whereas if the Size setting is set to true, I cannot change the font size.

This is documented behavior:

[Using the StyledSettings Property](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Setting_Text_Parameters_in_FireMonkey#Using_the_StyledSettings_Property)

> **When changing text representation properties of the TTextSettings type objects, remember that when you are changing the value of a property (of the TextSettings.Font.Size property in the previous example), then the actual changing of the object's view happens only if the ITextSettings.StyledSettings property does not contain the TStyledSetting.Size constant.** The "[Relation between TStyledSetting constants and TTextSettings properties](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.Graphics.ITextSettings)" table shows which TStyledSetting constants control handling of the TTextSettings text representation properties.

[FMX.Graphics.ITextSettings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.Graphics.ITextSettings)

> Remember that when you are changing the value of a property (for example of the TextSettings.FontColor property), then the actual changing of the control's view happens only if the StyledSettings property does not contain the TStyledSetting.FontColor constant. **The following table shows which TStyledSetting constants control handling of which TTextSettings text representation properties.**
>
> Relation between TStyledSetting constants and TTextSettings properties
>
> ```
> TStyledSetting   Dependent TTextSettings   Meaning 
>    Constant             Properties
>
> Family           TFont.Family              Font name. 
> Size             TFont.Size                Font size. 
> Style            TFont.Style               Font style (italic, bold). 
> FontColor        FontColor                 Font color. 
> Other            HorzAlign, VertAlign,     How to align and show the text.  
>                  Trimming, and WordWrap.
> ```

> So, when I create my custom control, I am trying to programmatically set the Size property to false, however I cannot figure out how to do so.

The correct syntax in C++ is:

```
Search->StyledSettings = Search->StyledSettings >> TStyledSetting::Size;
```

Comment: Man, this is helpful.  Thanks again to Remy.