# Set font settings dont works on create dynamic Label

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, c++builder, rad-studio

I am trying to set the font color and font size in a dynamically created `TLabel` object, but it does not work.

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TLabel *text;
    text = new TLabel(Form1);
    text->Parent = Form1;
    text->Align = TAlignLayout::Center;
    text->Margins->Top = 60;
    text->Font->Size = 13;   // don't works
    text->FontColor = TColorRec::Red;  // don't works
    text->Height = 17;
    text->Width = 120;
    text->TextSettings->HorzAlign = TTextAlign::Center;
    text->TextSettings->VertAlign = TTextAlign::Leading;
    text->StyledSettings.Contains(TStyledSetting::Family);
    text->StyledSettings.Contains(TStyledSetting::Style);
    text->Text = "My Text";
    text->VertTextAlign = TTextAlign::Leading;
    text->Trimming = TTextTrimming::None;
    text->TabStop = false;
    text->SetFocus();
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Not sure if it will make a difference, but try `text->TextSettings->FontColor = ...` and `text->TextSettings->Font->Size = ...`. However,  `text->StyledSettings.Contains(TStyledSetting::Family); text->StyledSettings.Contains(TStyledSetting::Style);` definitely does not do what you think it does, use: `text->StyledSettings = TStyledSettings() << TStyledSetting::Family << TStyledSetting::Style;` or: `text->StyledSettings = text->StyledSettings << TStyledSetting::Family << TStyledSetting::Style;` Not sure if you need to also add `TStyledSetting::FontColor` and `TStyledSetting::Size`, too.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i tested with your specifications but result are same :(

Comment: Are you able to set the font properties you want on a `TLabel` created on the Form at design-time?

Comment: in addition to  already stated stuff ... 1. `TColorRec::Red;` looks suspicios I do not use Delphi but in VCL: C++ Builder I would use `clRed` instead ...  2. `text->Font->Size` and `text->Font->Height` are rescaling each other. IIRC size is width and height is height of the font and the recomputed perameter will have negative value. Also IIRC you can not use any sizes they a re rounded to ones supported by the used font ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not removing items from `TStyledSettings` in order to enable your own settings. See [Setting Firemonkey control font programmatically in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30811392/setting-firemonkey-control-font-programmatically-in-c)

But then you are also using wrong color constants. Instead of `TColorRec::Red` you should use `TAlphaColor(claRed)`

This works:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TLabel *text;
    text = new TLabel(Form1);
    text->Parent = Form1;
    text->Position->X = 8;
    text->Position->Y = 50;
    text->Text = "My Text";

    // clear all styled settings to enable your own settings
//  text->StyledSettings = TStyledSettings(NULL);

    // alternatively clear only styled font color setting
    text->StyledSettings = text->StyledSettings >> TStyledSetting::FontColor;

    // and styled size setting
    text->StyledSettings = text->StyledSettings >> TStyledSetting::Size;

    // Firemonkey uses TAlphaColor colors
    text->FontColor = TAlphaColor(claRed);
    // alternatively:
    // text->FontColor = TAlphaColor(TAlphaColorRec::Red);
    // text->FontColor = TAlphaColor(0xFFFF0000); // ARGB

    text->Height = 20;
    text->Font->Size = 15;   // works now
}
```